# Sitecore disadvantage of using always the "master" database.

Tags: sitecore

Can some one tell me what will be the consequence of using the "master" database instead of web. I am talking about this:

```
    <site name="website">
        <patch:attribute name="database">master</patch:attribute>
        <patch:attribute name="language">en</patch:attribute>
    </site>
```

Comment: Do you mean development environment? Or live environment for CM or CD or both?

Comment: I am asking for live environment for CD. For development I am using Master.

Comment: You're basically referring to what Sitecore calls "Live Mode". Here is a good link that talks about the usages: http://www.verndale.com/insights/blog/2012/october/sitecore-live-mode/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bad practice to point a CD instance to a master database, because of security reasons, performance issues and many other functionalities that will break. The whole concept around Sitecore is to have a CD environment pointing to a web database, with no master db references.

- **Master**: Contains all versions of all content and media in all languages, including items with publishing restrictions.
- **Web**: The default publishing target database contains only the latest approved version in each language for each item.

Check the official guide from Sitecore:

> How to configure a content delivery server https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up__maintaining/xdb/configuring_servers/configure_a_content_delivery_server

Answer (score 0):

In a development environment this can be a good idea if you want to get rid of the need to publish, but in a production environment it's not a good idea at all.

You might end up with unexpected behavior as every save will immediately result in changes on the website. You will loose a lot of functionality like preview, scheduled publishing, workflow ...